# Search in many to many relation Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In Laravel I have this models:

```
class User {
        public function sites(){
                 return $this->belongsToMany(Site::class);
        }
}
```

and

```
class Site extends Model {
        public function users(){
                 return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
        }
}
```

In DB after migrations I have the table `site_user` with fields: `user_id` and `sites_id`.
Now, how can I retrieve for each users the sites al linked to him?

Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
$users = App\User::with('sites')->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check the link below  you need to pass the method name on query like below:

$users = App\Users::with('sites')->get();

for more information please visit:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

also this will help you to reduce the load on your query.